# Removing strings in front of object key

Tags: javascript, console.log

So I have to edit an entire array and decided to copy it from google, it returned to me this:

```
 {
 "name": "Tom",
 "age": 20
 }
 ...
```

Is it possible to copy the array without the "" around the object name?  Or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse() to parse the data

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp